# ActionScript 3 Best place to bind events

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am writing a small Flash game using air for android and have encountered a slight issue.
The game has 3 screens (excluding the game screen) which are main menu, load game & create new game. On the load game and create new game screens I want to add a button which take the user back to the main menu.

I know how to add event listeners to buttons but I am wondering where do I bind the event listener for back to main menu, binding in the constructor of my main class produces an error at run time and binding after going to the frame is knocking out the other buttons when back at the main screen.

At present the app is across multiple frames (probably a better structure to this instead of loading a single frame with each menu), I am new to actionscript so I am not entirely certain on best practices for this sort of thing.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add a warning when developing with Adobe AIR: It doesn't work on many mobile phones. I considered using Adobe AIR to develop but found out that my new HTC Wildfire S doesn't isn't supported by AIR. This is because of the type of processor

Comment: It is for a stupid class I had to take to make up credits, we HAVE to use air :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use only one frame in your Fla, then use a Document Class. In that main Class, you should place all your display objects using ActionScript.

I hope you know how to instantiate Class as library clips.